# Can not comprehend this circular dependency in Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Here is a simple Makefile that generates a circular dependency: test.cr <- test.cr.c

```
test: test.cr.c
    cp test.cr.c test

test.cr.c: test.cr
    cp test.cr test.cr.c
```

Why does GNU make consider this a circular dependency? How can I avoid it?

Comment: Please cut and paste the exact error message you get, with proper formatting.

Comment: Well its in german: 

`make: Zirkuläre Abhängigkeit test.cr <- test.cr.c wird nicht verwendet.`

prefixed with env LC_ALL=C it says:

`make: Circular test.cr <- test.cr.c dependency dropped.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `make -d` to see make's thinking.  In this rule:

```
test.cr.c: test.cr
        cp test.cr test.cr.c
```

You haven't provided make with any rule to build `test.cr` so make will go looking for one in its default rule set (run `make -pf/dev/null` to see the complete set of builtin rules).  It has a rule that knows how to build an executable from a `.c` file:

```
 %: %.c
        $(LINK.c) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

So it tries to see if this rule can be used to build `test.cr` from `test.cr.c`.  To do this it needs to see if it can update `test.cr.c` and it finds you provided a rule that builds `test.cr.c` from `test.cr`... now you have a circular dependency.

There are all kinds of ways to avoid this.  You can change your filename from `test.cr` to `test.cr.in` or something so it has a different relationship with `test.cr.c`.

You can remove all the built-in rules by running `make -r`.  Or, in new-enough versions of GNU make you can add `MAKEFLAGS += -r` to your makefile to turn off the built-in rules.

You can delete that particular built-in rule using:

```
%: %.c
```

(with nothing else).

You can declare a do-nothing explicit rule for `test.cr` so make doesn't search for one in its database, like this:

```
test.cr: ;
```

There are other ways, by adding `.cr` as a suffix.

Comment: Thanks! Good explanation. This behaviour of Make seemed a bit odd to me since test.cr is a real existing file.
However I went for the empty rule for test.cr:; That works fine, thank you!

Comment: Even real existing files need to be checked to see if they can be updated.  After all, after you run your build the first time the output files `test.cr.c` and `test` will also be "real existing files" :)

Comment: I do agree that this "match anything" built-in pattern rule (e.g., the target is just `%`) to build executables is unfortunate and the cause of much confusion.  It's not very useful either since it's exceedingly rare you can build an executable from a single source file like that.  But, it's been present in `make` for 40+ years so it's hard to change now.

Comment: For simple projects I find it actually useful to have that rule built in. But maybe this could be added to the catalogue here: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules